# Exporting vector from C4D to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cinema4d

I'm trying to export rendered object from Cinema 4D into Adobe Illustrator.

This is what I see in my render view of Cinema 4D:
[image]

This is what I see when opening exported .ai file in AI:
[image]

As you see object arrangement on the right side is totally screwed up. I've tried to turn off Layers option during export.
This text is created using Extrude NURBS if that makes any difference.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each letter is separate path. Turns out if I combine all paths into single, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the "Surface" shading options in the export window.